# Deployable content in a Visual Studio 2005 project... how?

Tags: visual-studio, build-process

I have a vanilla Visual Studio 2005 Solution with a single C++ Project which contains some non-code files that I would like to include in my build process.

For example, I have an .xml file with "Content" set to "True" in a path relative to my project directory. From my understanding this should be copied to the output directory in the same relative path from the project.

[alt text http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/9876/deployablecontent.gif](http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/9876/deployablecontent.gif)

However, nothing ever gets copied. What gives?

The directory structure is like this:

```
./           <- This is the project directory.
./content    <- This is where my "deployable" content is.
./include
./src
./build      <- This is the temp directory used when compiling.
./dist       <- This is the output directory.
```

After executing a debug build, I would expect my output to be like this:

```
./
./content
./include
./src
./build
./dist
./dist/debug             <- Compiled code is now here.
./dist/debug/content     <- My "deployable" files should be here.
```

In fact, setting "Content" to "True" (like in the provided screenshot) doesn't seem to be doing anything. Am I just misunderstanding how this works?

Comment: When I first read your title, I first thought you wrote "Deplorable content in a Visual C++ project"  :)  I think it's bedtime.

Comment: Hah! As it stands my content might as well be deplorable since I'm copying it manually to the output directory!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually copy additional files to output using Post-Build event, but your excellent question made me question my ways. I found that if you right-click on item and choose properties, a different dialog shows up, which allows you to specify what operation to perform during the build. However, I was not able to create a behaviour similar to what you want using standard windows commands. So you likely would need to write your own program to copy files to output.

Comment: I had thought about doing it this way (via post-build) but I had figured that this is a simple operation and should be doable in the normal build. Interestingly I cannot find anything about this on MSDN or their forums... a true mystery.

Comment: Ended up writing a script to copy the files and executed it with the post-build event...